# WiFi is missing suddenly in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi, system-settings, restart

WiFi is completely missing from PC suddenly, even setting doesn't show any WiFi option. This happened several times. Only after a complete restart it back again.

My OS is: "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS".
WiFi card name: "Intel Corp. Wireless 8265 / 8275 Wireless".

Comment: Please check BIOS revision version, flash BIOS if required. What is the branch of your laptop, and what type is it? This info can give us more insight. Try first of all unplugging the wifi card, and replug it + test/

Comment: My laptop model is "Asus Vivobook S15 S530UA" and sorry to say I am not capable of handling BIOS related work.

Comment: A Vivobook has a hardware switch for WiFi : did you check it's position? These are most likely hotkeys such as FN + F2 (depending on your model) . You can turn that off in the BIOS --- so you have to deal with BIOS setting wether you like it or not.